# Programmatically, how to write an unoptimized code to calculate the sum of 10 integers?

Tags: java, android, dalvik

In Java, C, or C++, how to write  an **unoptimized** code to calculate the sum of 10 integers (from 0 to 9) programmatically?

For example, I use the following code but it is seems that both codes (the ones labeled as //Baseline and //Method #1) are optimized by the compiler at the compile time and the total variables are converted to constants before runtime. I confirmed that by comparing the time1 and time2 which are similar.

**My question is**:

Programmatically, how to sum the 10 numbers and force the compiler not to optimize the code (no constant propagation/folding, for example) to avoid calculating the sum at compile time and **force it to happen only at runtime**?

```
       long start, end, time1, time2, total;

    //Baseline
    start = System.nanoTime();
    total = (0+1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9);
    end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("********************* The sum is " + total);
    time1 =  end - start;
    System.out.println("********************* start=" + start + " end=" + end + " time=" + time1);

    //Method #1
    start = System.nanoTime();
    total = (a0() + a1() + a2() + a3() + a4() + a5() + a6() + a7() + a8() + a9());
    end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("********************* The sum is " + total);
    time2 =  end - start;
    System.out.println("********************* start=" + start + " end=" + end + " time=" + time2);

}
private int a0()
{
    return 0;
}
private int a1()
{
    return 1;
}
private int a2()
{
    return 2;
}
private int a3()
{
    return 3;
}
private int a4()
{
    return 4;
}
private int a5()
{
    return 5;
}
private int a6()
{
    return 6;
}
private int a7()
{
    return 7;
}
private int a8()
{
    return 8;
}
private int a9()
{
    return 9;
}
```

**Updated Requirements:**

(1) Only for Java using Dalvik compiler

(2) Only primitive variables but nested functions (methods) are acceptable

(3) No volatile

(4) No loop, jump, or wait statements

By the way, I tried the suggested C and C++ suggestions below but non of them seem to work with Dalvik compiler where it converts the addition expression to a constant.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: have you tried volatile?

Comment: I doubt you can measure time of 10 additions this way

Comment: In C or C++ you would need to disable optimizations with a compiler flag

Comment: You should put the numbers in a container like an array or `std::vector` and sum them from the container.

Answer (score 1):

[godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) is a pretty cool online C++ compiler that conveniently shows assembly output.  I tried gcc, clang and icc and all of them optimised `1 + 2 + 3...` source code into a compile time result even at `-O0`, but if you code it [like this](http://goo.gl/fAvlQU):

```
// Type your code here, or load an example.
int main()
{
    register int sum = 1;
    sum += 2;
    sum += 3;
    sum += 4;
    sum += 5;
    sum += 6;
    sum += 7;
    sum += 8;
    sum += 9;
    return sum;
}
```

...you can get output like this (GCC 5.3.0 in this case)...

```
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    pushq   %rbx
    movl    $1, %ebx
    addl    $2, %ebx
    addl    $3, %ebx
    addl    $4, %ebx
    addl    $5, %ebx
    addl    $6, %ebx
    addl    $7, %ebx
    addl    $8, %ebx
    addl    $9, %ebx
    movl    %ebx, %eax
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

Clearly each add is being done separately.  This also avoids overheads of loop control which you'd have if you introduced a for loop with bounds only known at runtime.

Still, what does it mean?  There's no guarantee that the compiler will produce similar assembly given the same number of runtime-known variables....

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in C pretty easily by just disabling optimisations when you compile. Take this C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

And compile with `gcc -O0 program.c`. `-O0` tells GCC not to optimise your code. If you take a look at the outputted assembly (which you can do by adding `-S` as an argument to compilation), you can see that it is indeed summing the first 10 numbers:

```
...
LBB0_1:                                 ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    cmpl    $10, -24(%rbp)
    jge LBB0_4
## BB#2:                                ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movl    -24(%rbp), %eax
    addl    -20(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, -20(%rbp)
## BB#3:                                ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movl    -24(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $1, %eax
    movl    %eax, -24(%rbp)
    jmp LBB0_1
...
```

You can see the jump at the end of the snippet back to the start of the loop, and the conditional jump at the start of the loop to check `i < 10`. If you take a look at the optimised assembly code (compiling with `gcc -O3 -S program.c`), you can see GCC unrolls the loop and calculates the sum at compile time:

```
...
movl    $45, %esi
...
```

I have no idea why you want to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array (which is an object type in Java), and then in Java 8+ you could use [`IntStream.sum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--). Something like,

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
int sum = IntStream.of(arr).sum();
```

**or**

```
int sum = IntStream.range(0, 10).sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is **volatile**....

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void ) {

    volatile int n = 0;

    n += 1; n += 2; n += 3; n += 4; n += 5;
    n += 6; n += 7; n += 8; n += 9; n += 10;
    printf("%d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

[EDIT]
The addition appears to take place in a register, but there are two moves for each add:

```
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
    addl    $2, %eax
    movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)
```

Comment: `volatile` prevents the additions happening in a CPU register, making them massively slower.  Whether it's suitable depends on what the OP's trying to learn or test... your guess is as good as mine ;-).