# In Android, how to measure the execution time overhead programmatically?

Tags: java, android, performance, compiler-optimization, dalvik

Although there might be similar questions (such as [A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734660/programmatically-how-to-write-an-unoptimized-code-to-calculate-the-sum-of-10-in)), their answers do not solve my problem.

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 targeting Android API 18 (before Android KitKat 4.4, so I’m dealing with Dalvik, not ART runtime).

I have a modified Android that adds memory space overhead (specifically designed by the author and it is outside the scope of this question) with any used variables. For example, if we declare an integer variable, the variable will be stored in 8 bytes (64-bit) instead of 4 bytes (32-bit). This modification is completely transparent to apps which can run on the modified Android without any problem.

I need to measure that overhead in execution time, for example, when I use variables.

Here is what I did so far but it does not seems to work because the overhead variable (at the end of //Method #1 in the code below) is inconsistent, sometime it is negative, positive, or zero. In the ideal solution, it should be always (or at least most of the time) positive.

```
      long start, end, time1, time2, overhead;

    //Baseline
    start = System.nanoTime();
    total=0; total+=1; total+=2; total+=3; total+=4; total+=5; total+=6;
    total+=7; total+=8; total+=9;
    end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("********************* The sum is " + total);
    time1 =  end - start;
    System.out.println("********************* start=" + start + " end=" + end + " time=" + time1);

    //Method #1
    start = System.nanoTime();
    total = (a0() + a1() + a2() + a3() + a4() + a5() + a6() + a7() + a8() + a9());
    end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("********************* The sum is " + total);
    time2 =  end - start;
    System.out.println("********************* start=" + start + " end=" + end + " time=" + time2);

    overhead = time2 - time1;
    System.out.println("********************* overhead=" + overhead );    
}
private int a0()
{
    return 0;
}
private int a1()
{
    return 1;
}
private int a2()
{
    return 2;
}
private int a3()
{
    return 3;
}
private int a4()
{
    return 4;
}
private int a5()
{
    return 5;
}
private int a6()
{
    return 6;
}
private int a7()
{
    return 7;
}
private int a8()
{
    return 8;
}
private int a9()
{
    return 9;
}
```

**My question is:**

In Android, how to measure that execution time overhead programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is simply experimental error.

> the overhead variable is inconsistent, sometime it is negative,
>   positive, or zero. In the ideal solution, it should be always (or at
>   least most of the time) positive.

I don't have an exact solution for you problem on Android, but when I have done experimental testing in other contexts, I typically run multiple iterations and then divide by the number of iterations to get an average.

Here is some pseudocode:

```
int N = 10000;

startTimer();
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  runExperiment();
}
stopTimer();

double averageRuntime = timer / N;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code that you are trying to time is executing faster than the resolution of `System.nanotime()`. Try doing your additions in a loop, for e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    total += i;
}
```

Increase the loop count (1000) until you start getting reasonable elapsed times.